# Building tree structure from categories and sub categories and its sub categories

Tags: c#

I need to develop a tree structure between categories and subcategories.  I'm using a handler to generate the relation.

For example my SQL table contains

```
GlobalID for top-level parents 1000

Id      CategoryName          ParentId
 1        toyota               1000
 2        ford                 1000  
 5        prius                 1
 6        prius SP              5
 7        prius SP blue         6
 8        focus                 2
 9        mondeo                2 
 10       mustang               2
 11       focus EX              8
 ...
```

So the categories looks like

```
toyota 
   prius
     prius SP
       prius PS blue
  yaris
  auris

ford
  focus
    focus EX
  mondeo
  mustang
```

etc

---

To  do this Im using a recursive program whih will loop thorugh its child categories.

But How can I add the tree structure and send it back to the aspx page.

The code I'm using is

```
// To get all the parent categories

List<Category> objChildren = new List<Category>();

public List<Category> GetCategories(int categoryId)
{   
  IQueryable<Category> cats = from ca in db.Categories
                              where ca.ParentId == categoryId && ca.ParentId != nonPageId
                              select ca;

  return cats.ToList();
}

List<Category> parentCategories = GetCategories(1000);
foreach(Category _category in parentCategories)
{
  GetChildCats(_category);
}

public void GetChildCats(Category cat)
{
  objChildren.Add(cat);

  List<Category> cats = GetCategories(cat.CatId); 

  if (cats.Count != 0)
  { 
    foreach (Category cate in cats)
    {              
      GetChildCats(cate);               
    }
  }
}
```

How to return a JSON tree structure to the aspx page like this

```
</pre>
So the categories looks like
<pre>
[0] => toyota 
        [0] => prius
                [0] => prius SP
                         [0] => prius PS blue
        [1] => yaris
        [2] => auris

[1] => ford
        [0] => focus
                 [0] => focus EX
        [1] => mondeo
        [2] => mustang
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to instead of using 1000 use null. That will mean that the category has no parent (and not a parent with Id = 1000).

Then, map the relationship (Category Parent and IList Children) and you will be able to do this:

```
var parents = db.Categories.Where(x => x.Parent == null);
```

and the categories themself will be the tree structure you want and you will be able to use any JSON serializer.

Comment: Hi I think the parent id doesnt makes any difference as It can be kept null or 1000. But Im struggling at adding the child category list and its children in a nested manner to output the above mentioned JSON format. Im struggling to get that output. Thanks

Comment: It makes sense when EF tries to find a parent with Id 1000. Also from the database perspective, if you put 1000, you won't be able to make use of referencial integrity, you won't be able to put a FK there. If you have the object model, then any JSON serializer will do the job.